# task manager project - python

Tags: python, authentication

Just need some help with how to write code to read the total lines from 2 text files

```
 with open('user.txt','r') as admin_file:
      for line in admin_file:
      total = len(admin_file.readlines())
      print("Total number of users:", total)

 with open('tasks.txt','r') as admin_file:
      for line in admin_file:
      total = len(admin_file.readlines())
      print("Total number of tasks:", total)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you remove

```
for line in admin_file:
```

from both places, the code should work.
No need to loop through the lines here. Readlines already returns the list of all lines.

Comment: thank you Marc, seems to be working now when i ran it the first time it seems to have been counting from line 1 instead of starting from line 0